# connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:21 error in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I'm writing a simple application in node js, and i'm having this problem:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:21
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1034:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1057:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1099:14)
```

This is the script:

```
var Client = require('ftp');
var fs = require('fs');


  var c = new Client();
  c.on('ready', function() {
    c.get('/foo/foo1.txt', function(err, stream) {
      if (err) throw err;
      stream.once('close', function() { c.end(); });
      stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('foo.local-copy.txt'));
    });
  });
  c.connect('MYIP',21,false,'none','user','password',10000,10000,10000);

  c.end();
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Do you have FTP server listening on port 21? Do you have proper privileges set in this server for this credentials?

Comment: There’s no need to open port 21 for the insecure FTP protocol, and it’s actually a bad idea to do so because all data is transmitted unencrypted over FTP.

macOS has SSH support built-in, which uses port 22, which can be opened in System Preferences > Sharing > Remote Login. With this service enabled, any modern FTP client can use the much more secure SFTP protocol to connect to port 22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says the connection to port 21 was refused.

The most likely reason for this is that you aren't running an FTP server that is listening on that port.

You might also have firewalled it off (although that's unlikely on the loopback interface).

Comment: it's not a firewall problem.

Comment: @OiRc — I said that possibility was unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation said use an object in the connection parameters.

try this:

```
var Client = require('ftp');
var fs = require('fs');
var c = new Client();
c.on('ready', function() {
    c.list(function(err, list) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.dir(list);
        c.end();
    });
    c.put('foo.txt', 'foo.remote-tesssstt.txt', function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        c.end();
    });
});
// connect to localhost:21 as anonymous
c.connect({
    host: 'your_host', // ex: files.000webhost.com
    port: 21,
    user: 'your_user',
    password: 'your_password',
    secure: false,
    secureOptions: 'none',
    connTimeout: 10000,
    pasvTimeout: 10000,
    aliveTimeout: 10000
});
```