# Example node.js ftp server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ftp

I need to create a node.js app that connects to this ftp server and downloads files from this directory:

ftp://www.ngs.noaa.gov/cors/rinex/2021/143/nynb

I've tried following the `ftp` npm package docs but I feel like I am doing something horribly wrong:

```
import Client from "ftp";

/**
 * https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp
 */

const c = new Client();

c.on("ready", function () {
    c.get(
        "ftp://www.ngs.noaa.gov/cors/rinex/2021/143/nynb",
        (error, stream) => {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(`stream`, stream);
            stream.once("close", function () {
                c.end();
            });
        }
    );
});

// connect to localhost:21 as anonymous
c.connect();
```

When I run `npm run dev` with `nodemon` I get:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:21
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Can someone please help? I'm completely stumped.

Is it possible if someone could show me a small example of how I can connect to this remote ftp server?

Comment: Check this out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345523/connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-121-error-in-node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345523/connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-121-error-in-node-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few points :

- You're connecting to the local ftp with `c.connect();`. You need to connect to `www.ngs.noaa.gov` to download files from there.
- This path `cors/rinex/2021/143/nynb` is a directory on the remote host. `c.get` doesn't work, you need to list all files in the directory then download them 1 by 1.

The code below connect to the remote server and list all files in the directory

```
const Client = require('ftp');
const fs = require("fs");
const c = new Client();

c.on('ready', function () {
    c.list( "/cors/rinex/2021/143/nynb", function (err, list) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.dir(list);
    });
});

c.connect({
    host: "www.ngs.noaa.gov",
});
```